# How to add the placeholder in view exposed filter

Tags: views

I am just created a block-view with exposed filter in view,, now i want to give the placeholder to auto-complete widget type same as label name , how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add below code to form alter hook

```
$form['title']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Keyword search');
```